# Bulk insertion for file field

Tags: mysql, gwt, jdbc

I have problem for bulk insert of the file.I am saving the multiple record in mysql database with GWT from server side helper class.In that helper class, I have method for saving multiple record of the report object which is my domain class.Lets see code snippet below

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Report report = (Report) iterator.next();
    preparedStatment.setString(1, report.getTitle());
    preparedStatment.setString(2, report.getReportAbstract());
    preparedStatment.setString(3, report.getUrl());
    preparedStatment.setDate(4,(java.sql.Date) report.getPublishDate());
    preparedStatment.setString(5, report.getAuthor());
    preparedStatment.setString(6, report.getPublisher());
    preparedStatment.setDouble(7, report.getPrice());
    preparedStatment.setString(8, report.getCurrency());
    preparedStatment.setBoolean(9, report.isPurchase());
    **preparedStatment.setBinaryStream(10, inpStream,(int)inputFile.length());**
    preparedStatment.setString(11, report.getMimeType());
    preparedStatment.setBoolean(12, report.isDownload());
    preparedStatment.setLong(13, report.getReportSource());
    preparedStatment.setDate(14, new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));
    preparedStatment.setBoolean(15, report.isDeleted());
    preparedStatment.addBatch();
}    
int[] updateCounts = preparedStatment.executeBatch();
connection.commit();
```

In the above code,the line in bold font for sending file for insert.I looping and inserting one by one record.but It only insert  file for first record in database and for remaining  record that field is empty i.e no file insertion  but all fields are inserted properly.I stuck here for inserting file field for all record.
      Can anybody please help me on this?

Comment: Could you make your question bit clear.. What do you mean by **but It only insert only one file for one record in database but all fields are inserted properly** ??

Comment: but It only insert file for first record in database and for remaining record that field is empty i.e no file insertion but all fields are inserted properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your full code. You can try the following code,

> ```
> File TryFile = new File("yourFileName.txt");
> int TryFileLength = (int) TryFile.length();
> InputStream TryStream = (InputStream) new FileInputStream(TryFile);
> ```

and then in the Iterator just put the below code as a static one and lets see. If it works fine then pbm with your code only. Check the code before the Iterator.

> preparedStatment.setBinaryStream(10, TryStream,TryFileLength);

Correct me if i'm wrong..

Answer (score 0):

I am inserting same file for multiple record hence that file insert for only first record in database.For example,if i am trying to insert 5 record in bulk insert then i need to supply 5 different files,because each file instance we need to pass in the FileIputStream constructor.  when i was debug it and inspect the FileIputStream  object then  saw the some id in no. and FD=some no. present.I observed that, if this id and that FD have different values for each file then each file for specific  record inserted properly in Bulk insert.Thank you for your above replay..Correct me if i m technically wrong...